# Should I create a console application or a common library for it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm starting to implement the feature which outputs an excel file containing summary data retrieved from the database. It may take about 5 minutes to output it.
I need to implement the following two features for running the program.

1. outputting the excel file once a day (console application and windows task scheduler)
2. outputting the excel file and downloading it by clicking the 'download' button on the browswer (ASP.NET)

Now, I'm wondering which is the best way.

1. Just create the .exe file which outputs an excel file. It is scheduled to run once a day by the windows task scheduler and it also runs via the ASP.NET application using 'System.Diagnostics.Process'.
2. Create the common library which outputs an excel file. The library is used in the console application and also is used in the asp.net web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a dll and include it where u need it.
this is the most modular way...

(you can also create your exe file that use this dll)

Answer (score 1):

You should use windows service for this purpose and put timer in it for schedule execution.

So service will process/create the excel file at configured time and store it in configured location and from web application you can provide functionality download these excel files created by windows service.

Comment: Thank you Vijay. The function of the asp.net also need to create the excel file which contains fresh data before downloading it. Still should I use windows service?

Comment: You can create one class library to generate excel file and reference it to both the projects (Windows service/ASP.Net Application)

Answer (score 1):

Would use the second way (library). Its more flexibel when thinks change (for example new application which needs your excel or something else).

Answer (score 1):

Write a library that creates the excel-file and use this dll in a windows service and in the ASP.net website.